# What is wrong with this Ninject binding? Getting "no implicit reference conversion" error

Tags: c#, ninject

I am trying to bind `ICustomerRepository`:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository : IMongoRepository<Customer> { }

public interface IMongoRepository<T> : IMongoRepository { }

public interface IMongoRepository
{
    bool SaveToMongo(string contentToSave);
}
```

To `MongoRepository<Customer>`:

```
public class MongoRepository<T> : IMongoRepository<T>
{
    MongoDatabase _database;
    public MongoRepository(MongoDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public virtual bool SaveToMongo(string contentToSave)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

By doing this:

```
kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<MongoRepository<Customer>>().Named("Customer").WithConstructorArgument(kernel.TryGet<MongoDatabase>());;
```

But I am getting the error `The type 'MongoRepository<Customer>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<T1>.To<TImplementation>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MongoRepository<Customer>' to 'ICustomerRepository'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems strange that you have to define a type `ICustomerRepository` *and*  use `.Named("Customer")` too .

Comment: You're correct. It's left over from trying to switch from using `Named("Customer")` to using `ICustomerRepository`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to go that approach, what you would need to add is:

```
public class CustomerMongoRepository : MongoRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
....
}

Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerMongoRepository>()
.Named("Customer")
.WithConstructorArgument(kernel.TryGet<MongoDatabase>());
```

But since you've got 50 entities it seems unlikely that you'll want to create 50 Repository Implementations, all doing nothing but inheriting from `MongoRepository<T>`.

So why don't you just skip the `ICustomerRepository` interface altogether and instead settle with `IMongoRepository<Customer>`?

```
Bind(typeof(IMongoRepository)).To(typeof(MongoRepository))
    .WithConstructorArgument(kernel.TryGet<MongoDatabase>());
```

Which you can then use like: `kernel.Get<IMongoRepository<Customer>>();`
(or, of course and much better, have it injected into a constructor).